# Set validity of multiple inputs from a AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which can be used to reset validation status of multiple input controls in a group, when one of the control's value is changed. Groups are identified by the attribute of the directive set in HTML.
Ex: - Both of the **From Date** and **To Date** inputs resets the validity state when one of the controls input value is changed by the user

This is what I have so far

**JS/Angular**

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('groupedInputs', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.on('change', function () {

                // Resetting own validity
                scope.$apply(ctrl.$setValidity('server', true));

                // Here I need to set the validity of the controls which
                // have the `GroupedInputs` directive with the 
                // same  attribute value
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="FromDate" type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="model.FromDate" grouped-inputs="FromToDates">
<input name="ToDate" type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="model.ToDate" grouped-inputs="FromToDates">
```

It can reset the validity of the own input control, but can not access the other input controls with directive and same attribute value. What is the best possible angular way to access the other controls by querying the inputs with the same attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try to approach this problem by implementing helper object to store group elements controllers with methods to add to the group and setValidity of all elements in the group.

Something like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('groupedInputs', function() {

    var groupControls = {
        groups: {},
        add: function(name, ctrl) {
            this.groups[name] = this.groups[name] || [];
            this.groups[name].push(ctrl);
        },
        setValidity: function(name, key, value) {
            this.groups[name].forEach(function(ctrl) {
                ctrl.$setValidity(key, value);
            });
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            // Add element controller to the group
            groupControls.add(attrs.groupedInputs, ctrl);

            element.on('change', function() {

                // When needed, set validity of elements in the group
                groupControls.setValidity(attrs.groupedInputs, 'server', false);
                scope.$apply();

            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fusaaN6k9J5SZ7iQA97V?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the controllers having the same group in an array:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('groupedInputs', function () {
    var controllersPerGroup = {};

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var groupName = attrs.groupedInputs;
            var group = controllersPerGroup[groupName];
            if (!group) {
                group = [];
                controllersPerGroup[groupName] = group;
            }
            group.push(ctrl);

            element.on('change', function () {

                // Resetting own validity
                scope.$apply(ctrl.$setValidity('server', true));

                // all the other controllers of the same group are in the groups array.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Don't forget to take care of removing the controllers once the element is destroyed, by listening to the `$destroy` event.