# Apply 'required' validation on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with **text boxes, date pickers and drop downs**. Once I enter a value in any field, then I want others to be required: that means if I enter a value in a first text box, then all the other fields must be required. If I select a date, then all the textboxes and drop downs are mandatory. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409910/set-validity-of-multiple-inputs-from-a-angularjs-directive/#30410211)  SO answer, I got the result only on text boxes, but not with drop downs and date pickers.

Thanks.

Comment: post some of your code and someone might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through each element in javascript and set attribute `required="required"` to it.

i.e., you can try

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs");
for(i =0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
{
  inputs[i].setAttribute("required", "required");
}
```